# How to get exif command for image via url form S3 in react?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, image-processing, orientation

I was uploading images to **S3** and there are some images whose orientation is not correct when view at the ReactJS end with s3 URL. I have used different Packages but can't auto rotate because can't get exif data with **image url**.
Packages example :

```
react-exif-orientation-img
react-fix-image-orientation
blueimp-load-image
```

Please guide me, what i am doing wrong?